# Software/game to project/extract person/silhouette from a webcam and project it into a pc game or a virtual reality environment?

Tags: game, webcam, vr

Is there some software/game to project/extract person/silhouette from a webcam and project it into a pc game or a virtual reality environment, such an idea like this crossed my mind, and I think, it could be a very enjoyable experience.

Answer (score 0):

There are smartphone apps like Scandy Pro which can scan a 3D object and export them as a 3D model for use as an asset in Unity (which I assume is the engine you're running VR from.) You basically scan over every surface of the object, then it builds it from these frames as a 3D model which can be thrown into Unity.

Comment: Yes, thank you, interesting concept on one side, on other side I would prefer perhaps realtime , even though scanning is interesting too, and maybe tracking also what you are wearing, in an online conference etc

Comment: Tracking? Like MoCap (Motion Capture)? Adobe and Autodesk have good tools for that, but they'd require peripherals and spaces to capture said motion. Realtime I don't know about, but MoCap has been used in games like Mortal Kombat to make realistic character movement.